How can I better add dependencies?
I'm a hobbyist relearning Android from scratch, but I'm spending less than 1% of my time coding because I constantly encounter the issue of references not being recognized, with no suggested solution.
For context, I made several complete apps back in the Gingerbread/Honeycomb days, and I remember was just right-click --> import --> done. I don't think I was even aware of Gradle files or the word "dependency", and I want that experience again. Do I just have a rosy-filtered view of the past???
Here's a real example that illustrates it.
In android.com's Cupcake App, CupcakeScreen.kt has this code:
@Composable
fun CupcakeApp(
    viewModel: OrderViewModel = viewModel(),
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
) {

    Scaffold(
    ...

I want to add the same viewModel line to my app, so I paste the line, along with the same import statement the Cupcake app uses:
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel

@Composable
fun GotubeApp(
    viewModel: GotubeViewModel = viewModel(),
) {

The word compose in the import line highlights in red, and hovering it gives the error message, "Unresolved reference: compose", with no suggestion to fix it.
I figure this is a problem with missing dependencies, so I look in the Cupcake app's build.grade.kts:app, and see several dependencies that might be the one, but none that clearly match:
dependencies {

    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01"))
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime")
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:${rootProject.extra["lifecycle_version"]}")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:${rootProject.extra["lifecycle_version"]}")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:${rootProject.extra["lifecycle_version"]}")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:${rootProject.extra["lifecycle_version"]}")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.4")

    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
}

I don't know which, if any of these I should use, so I consult Android's Lifecycle page, which gives a list:
    // ViewModel
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    // ViewModel utilities for Compose
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycle_version")
    // LiveData
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    // Lifecycle utilities for Compose
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:$lifecycle_version")

    // Saved state module for ViewModel
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version")

...

I go through them one at a time from the top until the error on "compose" disappears.
That's a lot of work for one line of code, and nearly every line I add sends me through a similar routine. Is this what Android development is like now, or can I be doing better?

Did you see that the reference docs for every method tell you exactly which artifact that method is in?

@ianhanniballake I didn't know that, and that's probably exactly what I need. When I try searching for it, say with "android viewModel reference", I get hits for the ViewModel page, which doesn't include reference for the viewModel method. Without already knowing which library I should be using, how would I find that page?

I used the search on developer.android.com and put in androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel and it was the first result.

@ianhanniballake Thanks. If you frame this as an answer that addresses the problem in general, possibly using my example as illustration, I'll give it a checkmark.


In android.com's Cupcake App, CupcakeScreen.kt has this code

Step #2 of that tutorial has you download and open a starter project that has all the dependencies declared. This way, they do not need to go through each and every dependency as part of that tutorial, focusing instead on the code.
You must have missed that step.

I made several complete apps back in the Gingerbread/Honeycomb days, and I remember was just right-click --> import --> done

That would have been with Eclipse. Android app development was in the "rank amateur" phase, and proper dependency management (e.g., versioning) was not part of our process. We have matured as an industry since then, though there is still plenty of room for further growth.
Note that there are also a lot more libraries now than a decade-and-change ago. A 1000x fold increase seems like it might be about right. How many of those you choose to use is up to you.

can I be doing better?

Asking the question "what dependency do I need in order to use this line of code that I wish to copy?" is fairly typical. For the Jetpack libraries, as Google's Ian Lake noted in a comment, the documentation nowadays points to the dependency, if one is needed.

For third-party libraries, often the documentation points out where to get their library as one of the first items (e.g., in a GitHub README).

I'm a hobbyist relearning Android from scratch

You might consider relearning from a book or course, as they will be explaining the use of popular libraries, including what the dependencies are. Things have changed a lot in Android app development in the past decade.

I've already cloned the starter project, which is how I have the list of dependencies. My issue is that I don't know how to determine from that which dependency goes with the one method that I want to add to my own app, especially when I copy code from the web, which often only includes import statements, not dependencies.
